# Proof of Identity Involving Binomial Coefficients

Tags: proof-verification, binomial-coefficients, solution-verification

I am new to stack exchange. I can't find a duplicate of this problem (some similar but I am stuck at a specific place!).

I need to prove:

$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n-r+1}{r} \binom{n}{r-1}$

I know that  n choose k can be rewritten,

$\binom{n}{r} =\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+2)(n-r+1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3...(r-1)\cdot r}$

Further rewritten as,

$\frac{1}{r}\binom{n}{r-1} =\frac{1}{r}\cdot \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+2)(n-r+1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3...(r-1)}$

Now I need to pull out the (n-r+1) term from the numerator. How do I do this without effecting the n choose k term? To show my question, if I pull out n-r+1 do I have,

$\frac{(n-r+1)}{r}\binom{n-1}{r-1} =\frac{(n-r+1)}{r}\cdot \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+2)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3...(r-1)}$

Or do I have my answer? What am I missing here?

(I used http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php to format my question so I hope it comes out as intended, and that I have included the correct tags..)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Notice, $$RHS=\frac{n-r+1}{r}\binom{n}{r-1}$$
$$=\frac{n-r+1}{r}\frac{n!}{(n-(r-1))!(r-1)!}$$
$$=\frac{n-r+1}{r}\frac{n!}{(n-r+1)!(r-1)!}$$
$$=\frac{(n-r+1)n!}{[(n-r+1)\cdot  (n-r)!]\cdot [r\cdot (r-1)!]}$$
$$=\frac{(n-r+1)n!}{(n-r+1)[(n-r)!]\cdot [r\cdot (r-1)!]}$$
$$=\frac{n!}{[(n-r)!]\cdot [r!]}$$$$=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!\cdot r!}$$ $$=\color{red}{\binom{n}{r}}=LHS$$

Comment: Ah, I see that I was approaching the problem the hard way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You said $$\frac{1}{r}\binom{n}{r-1} =\frac{1}{r}\cdot \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+2)(n-r+1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3...(r-1)},$$ but this is not correct. To get the right-hand side, you rewrote $\binom{n}{r}$, so what would have been correct to say at that point is $$\binom{n}{r} =\frac{1}{r}\cdot \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+2)(n-r+1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3...(r-1)}.$$ Can you proceed from there?

Comment: I see my error, thank you!